# React JS Problems to manage Checkbox Table Sellect All and unsellect one with react Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So, I'm trying to find a way to fix a problem in React JS Table with Checkbox.

I've created a React Table with .map() function from an Array JSON, in one of this Columns I've had the input to sellect one item and that works fine, but when I try click on Sellect All Checkboxes I've a problem. So, first my function AllCheck() is that:

```
const allCheck = () => {
        let a = []

        proList.map((i,t)=>{
            return a.push({'product_id': `${i.product_id}`})
        })
        setArrayChangeItens(a)
        getListProd()
    }
```

In my Table Column the individual checkbox makes checked when I click on all, but is uncliclable after.
I've tried make one verification on defaultChecked={arrayChangeItens.includes(i.product_id)} but no answer. I'm using React Hooks.

This is my td for sellect one item:

```
<td>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={selectedItems.includes(i.product_id)} onChange={()=>itensToArrayChange(i.product_id)} className="act" id="act" name="bulk" />
 </label> 
</td>
```

And this is my code for function for addOne Item only:

```
function itensToArrayChange(e) {
    let a = { product_id: `${e}` };
    let it = arrayChangeItens;

    if (arrayChangeItens.some((item) => item.product_id === `${e}`) == false) {
        arrayChangeItens.push(a);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayChangeItens.length; i++) {
            if (arrayChangeItens[i].product_id == e) arrayChangeItens.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    console.log(arrayChangeItens);
}
```

Thank you so much.